# Moving the displayed price to a different block

Tags: magento-1.9, price, local.xml

I'm trying to change the layout in a Magento template to have the price (and some other information) on a left column and the images/content of the product in the right.

my local.xml:

```
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>page/2columns-left-special.phtml</template>
        </action> 

    </reference>        
    <reference name="leftprice">
        <block type="core/template" name="leftprice" template="catalog/product/leftprice.phtml" before="-"/>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

This loads the correct template (2columns-left-special). In that template I've got this code:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('content') ?>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('leftprice') ?>
```

Content loads fine. Leftprice loads nothing.

There is a template file at

```
theme_name/template/catalog/product/leftprice.phtml
```

But this is ignored and doesn't show anything. What am I missing in the local.xml that tells Magento to load the proper template?

Comment: why you have call multiple core block name with same name  leftprice.. also tell me  why have you added <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('leftprice') ?> at 2columns-left-special.phmtl

Comment: Copied an existing template that calls $this->getChildHtml('left'), if this isn't how to to call this block how should I be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use this code

```
 <reference name="left">
    <block type="core/template" name="leftprice" template="catalog/product/leftprice.phtml" before="-"/>
</reference>
```

Certain points I need to mention here is

- `leftprice` block is not a default block in Magento. It's a custom block. May be it is used by your custom theme. So make sure `app\design\frontend\[package]\[theme]\template\catalog/product/leftprice.phtml` does exist.
- Note that you need to include `leftprice` block inside `left` block. `left` block is  a default structural block in Magento which is used to hold block that should appear in left section of the layout. What you have done here is absolutely wrong. You are trying to include `leftprice` block inside `leftprice` block !!
- I am not understanding why `leftprice` block call is present in `2columns-left.phtml` file (`<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('leftprice') ?>`). 
  The block call that should present in `2columns-left.phtml` is..

  ```
  <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('left') ?>
  ```

So.. If you are responsible for adding that code, then better remove it from there. The above two steps are enough for displaying `leftprice` block in left section

After all, don't forget to remove the caches. :-)

Comment: Awesome! works now. Just some notes: I made the leftprice.phtml block and 2columns-left-special.phtml to experiment, they aren't default. Why can't I define my own reference named leftprice and include a leftprice block (or any other block name) inside it? Why am I restricted to the left reference name?

Comment: because as I pointed out in my answer `left` block is a structural block and it has lot of specialities. It can render its child blocks content automatically. Whereas `leftprice` block is a "normal" block. It does not have the power of a structural block.

Comment: Yeah I gathered it was special... sorry if i'm banging my head against your answer, but is there a list somewhere of all the special blocks / or a place where they exist in code that makes it clear why they are special compared to regular blocks? I'd hazard a guess the `right` block is the same as the `left` one with special capabilities for instance.

Comment: left, right, content blocks are structural blocks and they will behave in the same manner. Only difference is content will appear in different section. "Why it happens" is a too broad question and I cant answer that question via a comment. If you have more doubts, feel free to ask another question. Understanding Magento layout structure and processing will take some time. Practice Practice Practice. You will reach there soon